# When going to render mode i can't see other objects only my modeled object

Tags: rendering, objects, camera, light

So i have a pretty basic scene just a cat, a lamp set to sun, a camera and an empty object. But when going to render mode to see how light is falling on my cat i can't see my other objects. [image: (Object mode)]

[image]

Please help me, if you didn't understand what i said please leave me a comment, thanks!

Comment: Light and camera will not show up in render result, I can see the issue with eyes texture, Is it your problem?

Comment: No as you can see there are no light nor camera as in the previous screenshot which is object mode, i fixed the problem with the eyes. The problem was that i cant see the light not the camera. Thanks

Comment: Have a nice time :)

Comment: You dont know why i cant see my other objects?

Comment: Camera and light will not show up in render mode, this is the default function of the blender

Comment: Yes right... Thanks for answering so quickly, I just got mistaken. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, if with "other objects" you are referring to the cube that's visible in the first image, it seems to be a "wireframe" object (maybe you switched its maximum draw mode to "wireframe") so it's invisible in renders... otherwise, please specify better what you are not seeing...

Comment: No, it is just i got confused with render mode and material mode, lol. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks, Please accept the answer, so it may be useful for others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camera and light will not show up in render mode, this is the default function of the blender.

Answer (score 3):

Render mode renders your final result in which wireframe objects will not show (that is by design as that is not desirable).

That render mode is interactive, so you can have 2 3d viewports open, one in shaded/wireframe/material mode so you can see all the objects and the other in render preview to see the lighting. What you do in 1st will update in 2nd. For Cycles and Blender Internal render engines the response will not be realtime though.

As you are using Blender Internal and there is no Global Illumination, you can get a phong shading preview also by switching from Multitexture to GLSL shaded viewport. Note that only spot lamps will produce shadows. You will get the same shading as in Blender Game engine.

You can also download an EEVEE Blender testbuild and play with this new realtime engine. You will be able to see all the wireframe in viewport an the shading at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! How can i get EEVEE? is there a website for it or something? Thanks again!

Comment: @AntonPg It is included in the 2.8 version testbuilds: https://builder.blender.org/download/